# How to prevent default on a button click

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following code submits a form using an onclick event for an anchor tag.  The code below it submits the same form using an onclick event in a button.  The first form (the onclick event from anchor tag) prevents default.  The second form (onclick button event) does not.

```
    <div class="center_text_grid flex-item EMail_Pwd">
    <button href="google.com" class="btn_joinnow" id="btn_submit" style="color:rgb(255,255,255)">Submit Information</button></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$("#btn_submit").on("click", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    form_data = $('form').serialize()
    console.log("Okay, I'm starting");
    console.log(form_data);
    return $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "echo_test.php",
        data: form_data,
        success: function (responseText) {
            console.log(responseText);
        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.log("Okay, I failed" + error);
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

This code (onclick button event) does not prevent default:

```
  <div class="EMail_Pwd_JoinPage"><button class="btn_joinnow" style="color:rgb(255,255,255);" id="btn_submit" onclick="GetDate(); GetCkBx(); CollectData();">Submit Information</button></div>

<script>
function CollectData() {
    form_data = $('form').serialize()
    console.log("CollectData");
    console.log("Okay, I'm starting");
    console.log(form_data);
    return $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "register.php",
        data: form_data,
        success: function (responseText) {
            /*console.log(responseText);
        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.log("Okay, I failed" + error);
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

My question is:  how can I prevent default on a button onclick event function like I can with an onclick from an anchor tag.

Comment: well where is the preventDefault() code??? First one has it, second one does not...........................

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the event parameter to the CollectData and prevent default action like you do in the first case:

```
<div class="EMail_Pwd_JoinPage"><button class="btn_joinnow" style="color:rgb(255,255,255);" id="btn_submit"
                                    onclick="GetDate(); GetCkBx(); CollectData(event);">Submit Information</button></div>



function CollectData(event) {
     event.preventDefault();
     .........
```

Comment: Great @gaetanoM -- that's the right answer.  Thanks so much.